# R: Summary using dplyr group_by function does not group

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

I have a simple dataset called `dt`, with some ordinal scaled values and a variable called `group` containing three groups. I try to calculate the summary statistics of one variable `dt[,24]` by doing this.

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% group_by(group) %>% 
  summarize(
    n = n(),
    mean=mean(dt[,24], na.rm = TRUE), 
    sum=sum(dt[,24], na.rm = TRUE),
    std = sd(dt[,24], na.rm = TRUE)
    )
```

Unfortunately, the output for each group is exactly the same.

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  group     n  mean   sum   std
  <ord> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 1       452  2.56  2266  1.13
2 2       308  2.56  2266  1.13
3 3        81  2.56  2266  1.13
4 NA       97  2.56  2266  1.13
```

When I try to calculate it via a simple for-loop, the results do differ.

```
for (index in c(1,2,3)){
  print(mean(dt[dt$group==index,24],na.rm = TRUE))
}

[1] 2.488599
[1] 2.259259
[1] 2.654867
```

It appears that the dplyr summary function only calculates the global mean. **What is going wrong?** I followed the exact steps as on this page: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/kruskal-wallis-test-in-r

Comment: `sum(dt[,24], na.rm = TRUE)` is the error. use the collumn name. You calculate for each row the sum of the whole collumn.

Comment: Ah thank you, the colnames were rather lenghty. That's why I kept using `dt[,24]`. Makes sense that that won't work. Thanks

Comment: If you want to avoid typing the colnames, you can also use `summarize_at`: 
`grouped_dt %>% summarize_at(24, funs(n=length, mean, sum, std))`